# Rails Form Object show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am trying to figure out how to write the show action for Form Objects.

The following is code taken from RailsCast episode 416 [project](https://github.com/railscasts/416-form-objects/tree/master/signup-after)

**app/forms/signup_form.rb**

```
class SignupForm
  # Rails 4: include ActiveModel::Model
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  def self.model_name
    ActiveModel::Name.new(self, nil, "User")
  end

  validates_presence_of :username
  validate :verify_unique_username
  validates_format_of :email, with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/
  validates_length_of :password, minimum: 6

  delegate :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, to: :user
  delegate :twitter_name, :github_name, :bio, to: :profile

  def user
    @user ||= User.new
  end

  def profile
    @profile ||= user.build_profile
  end

  #...
end
```

**app/controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @signup_form = SignupForm.new
  end

  def create
    @signup_form = SignupForm.new
    if @signup_form.submit(params[:user])
      session[:user_id] = @signup_form.user.id
      redirect_to @signup_form.user, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = current_user
  end
end
```

I don't see how one would pass in the ID of the model and specify the variables.

Does anyone have an example or can provide one using the episode's code as a starting point?

Comment: You are unlikely to get an answer to a question that includes no code and links to a subscription only railscast. Can I suggest you make more of an effort with your question to make it specific and include your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular episode abstracts the form building into a separate folder in the app path. You have go into the views folder to see how it is being used. Specifically, [here](https://github.com/railscasts/416-form-objects/blob/master/signup-after/app/views/users/new.html.erb).

This is where all of the variables are set that are passed as part of the `sessions/signup` routes that are defined in the [routes.rb file](https://github.com/railscasts/416-form-objects/blob/master/signup-after/config/routes.rb).

However, a typical `show` action would not have a form as it usually would display the information pertaining to the record queried. The `edit` action is used to display the form and pass to the `update` action. In that form, you would have the fields for the user information and you would provide a `hidden_field :id` helper that would indicate the id of the user being updated. That, or use the routes parameter and instantiate it in the `update` action prior to saving the changes from the passed `params` hash.

That particular project does not have edit/update actions in it though.